# image auto rotate counterclockwise when width is less than height

Tags: html, image, autorotate

My all images auto rotate counterclockwise when width is less than height.

Example: [`this example`](https://codepen.io/TaNoBi/pen/pZPZxE)

Help me please! Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, does it happen for you in the codepen you provided? I'm not seeing it on Edge or Chrome in that codepen. It could be because of one of the classes on that image that aren't defined in the code pen.

Comment: Hi @pepperjack, I use chrome, I fixed link example, I mistake link :). Can you see again? Thanks

Comment: I still don't see it. Please check your chrome plugins.